# Replace default button icons in the index view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I've generated MVC5 application which have table in the main screen (use default generation)

in the last column there is buttons for edit /details/delete .

1.how should I replace the button with icon for example pen for edit ,X for delete...

2.The create new is in the left side of the table how should I move it to the right side?

This is the default generated screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u are using twitter bootstrap then u can do this like follwing. Use your css class instead of mine. That's it

```
<td>
     @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new {id = item.Id}, new {@class = "btn btn-mini btn-success icon-eye-open bigger-120"})
     @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new {id = item.Id}, new {@class = "btn btn-mini btn-info icon-edit bigger-120"})                 
     @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new {id = item.Id}, new {@class = "btn btn-mini btn-danger icon-trash bigger-120"})
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Azin,its working but I want to use different icon which I want to put in the mvc project,How can I add the icon and refer to it in the code.Thanks,Voted up!

Comment: then u can use <img> tag inside <a> tag like this:
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", new {id = item.Id})"><img src="smiley.gif"></a>

Answer (score 0):

These are more html/css questions.

You can `float` the div/span of the `Create New` to the `right`. For the `Edit/Details/Delete`, you can just replace them with `<img>` tags for each one and wrap each of them in `<a>` tags.

Comment: Thanks but the for the create new is like following ,how should I Float it to the right?     <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>